# Store several different .git branches in the same directory?

Tags: git, git-branch

There was no local .git repository on Windows in a "..Downloads/Training" folder, using per-installed git bash, I first typed

```
git init
```

`touch .gitignore` in acccordance with the youtube tutorial (see link listed below) copied .gitignore file contents from previously created by visual studio repository, also added .gitignore by
`git add .gitignore` , also added the only subfolder M01 in "..Downloads/Training" by typing
`git add .`, commited the changes by
`git commit -am "First commit"`, added the remote by typing
`git remote add origin https:name_of_remote.com/my_repository_folder`, created a branch
`git branch M01`, switched to the branch by
`git switch M01`, also pushed the repo by typing
`git push origin HEAD:M01`.
And the repository has been pushed successfully into that remote but now there is a problem:
I need to store the contents of each folder inside "..Downloads/Training" in a separate branch on the remote.

So if I create a new local folder M02 and a branch by typing `git branch M02`, switching to it by `git switch M02`, It shows me all of the contents that I have previously added into the M01 branch in the M02 branch, but If I remove the files from M02 by typing `git rm . -r` (it deletes local files), it also deletes the files from both M01 branch and M02 branch.

Is there a way to store only M01 local folder in a M01 branch and the M02 local folder in a M02 branch?

Additional source tutorial links:
(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g4BJXfmAevA)

Comment: If you want unrelated code that is "exclusive" of each other, you should have different repositories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have learned some things that are wrong.  Note: I have not watched the particular youtube tutorial you linked, so I'm not sure if it is good, bad, or indifferent.  I base this paragraph solely on what you wrote in your question.

First, let's address what a Git repository is and is not:

- A Git repository *is* a *collection of commits*.  These commits are to be found using branch names, tag names, and other names, but it's not a collection *of branches*.  It's a collection *of commits*.  A loose analogy might be a collection of insects, where you label the insects: that makes the collection *contain* labels, but it's not a collection *of* labels.  That is, the labels aren't the purpose of the collection.
- The actual repository proper is stored in the `.git` directory (or folder, if you prefer that term).  The existence of this folder, with specific files and sub-folders that Git will need, is what tells Git that this *is* a repository.  If the `.git` directory itself is absent, or is missing these crucial files and/or sub-folders, Git will say that this is not a Git repository.
- A *bare* repository starts and ends with the `.git` folder (which is then often named `repo.git` or some such, rather than just `.git`).  Technically a bare repository still has an index / staging-area, but that's just because Git's implementation *of* the index / staging-area is mainly a file in the `.git` directory, named `index`.  (This file does not have to exist: Git will create it if needed.)
- A *non-bare* repository, which is the kind you would normally work with, also has a *working tree*.  The working tree is where you see and work with your files.  These files are ordinary, everyday files on your computer, stored in folders the way your computer likes to store files.  It's important to understand that these working tree files *are not in the Git repository*.
- The repository—the `.git` folder—stores commits and other internal Git objects.  These take the form of an *object database*, in which Git looks up objects by their hash IDs: large, random-looking numbers, expressed in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal).  All of these objects are in fact read-only: once stored in the database, no object can ever be changed.  This means no commit or file can ever be changed.
- The repository also stores a separate database of names: branch names, tag names, remote-tracking names, and other names.  Each of these stored names holds exactly one hash ID.  For branch names, the stored hash ID is always that of a commit.  (Tag names are allowed to store other internal-Git-object hash IDs, that you don't normally interact with as directly.)  This serves as a good (and fast) way to find particular commits.

Finding, extracting, using, and creating new commits is much of what we do with a Git repository.  Since the repository is so commit-centric—and what we do *with* the repository is *definitely* commit-centric—it's important to know what a commit is and does, *and* how Git extracts one:

- Each commit stores a full snapshot of all of your files.  The files inside the commits are *not* in the ordinary computer file form.<sup>1</sup>  Because they are stored as Git objects, they're all *read-only*.  Not even Git can change them.  And, because the commit itself is a Git object, it has one of those big ugly hash IDs, so that Git can look it up in the database of objects.
- Each commit also stores some *metadata:* information about the commit itself, such as who made it and when.  In this metadata, Git stores the hash ID of a *previous* commit.  More precisely, *most* commits store the hash ID of *one* previous commit, but there are some exceptions to this rule.

Because each commit is read-only, but you normally need to read *and write* your files, you'll tell Git to *extract* some commit.  When you do that, Git will copy the files *out* of the commit.  To do so, Git will read out the internal-only, read-only data from the internally stored files (with their internally-stored names) and turn that into the ordinary file-in-folder setup that your computer uses.  Those files will go into your *working tree*.

In other words, when you run `git checkout` or `git switch`, Git performs an optimized (and safety-checked) variant of the following two-step sequence:

- First, Git **removes all the (tracked) files from your working tree**.
- Then, Git **replaces all the files in your working tree** with those from the commit you just checked out.

This is *why* each commit stores every file: because switching from one commit to another will remove all the files from the commit you're *leaving behind*, and extract, instead, all the files from the commit you're *moving to*.  **The commits themselves are completely read-only, so no commit changes in this process, and no files are lost.**  Only your *working tree* is emptied and re-filled.

Note that this talks about switching from one **commit** to another.  Switching from one *branch* to another doesn't necessarily switch *commits*.  To understand this correctly, we should draw a picture of the commits.

---

<sup>1</sup>They are stored in a special, read-only, Git-only form, where they are compressed and—important for Git's internal operations—*de-duplicated*.  This de-duplication step allows every commit to store *every* file, without taking any extra space.  In fact, many different files—plus other internal Git objects—may be stored inside a single computer file (named with some big ugly hash ID followed by `.pack`), although sometimes file contents are stored as what Git calls *loose objects*.  Either way, though, these files do not have ordinary file names, either.

---

#### Drawing pictures of commits in branches

Each commit has some big, ugly, random-looking hash ID.  Rather than using these, let's use single uppercase letters to stand in for the hash IDs.  And, most commits contain the hash ID of some *previous* commit.  Rather than using that, let's draw an arrow, pointing from the later commit *to* the previous commit.  We'll start with some commit whose hash ID is `H`:

```
            <-H
```

The commit `H` points backwards to, we'll call commit `G`:

```
        <-G <-H
```

`G` of course points to another, still-earlier commit, so we have to keep going:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

Eventually we'll have a chain of commits that points all the way back to the very first commit ever.  Let's call that `A` here, and draw in all the commits—but I'll get a bit lazy now and use lines to connect them, even though the arrows really only point *backwards*.  Git can't go in and adjust the earlier commit to point forwards, because the earlier commit is frozen for all time, once it's made.  So we have:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H
```

Here, commit `H` is the *last* commit in the chain.  From `H` we—or Git—can work our way all the way back to the *first* commit in the chain, commit `A`; there, everything stops, because there are no earlier commits.

To find commit `H` *quickly*, we give it a *branch name*, like `main` or `master`.<sup>2</sup>  To represent this, let's put in the name, with an arrow coming out of it, pointing to commit `H`:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
```

If you now create a *new* **name**, such as `M01`, that *name* selects the *same commit*, by default.  We now have two names for commit `H`:

```
...--G--H   <-- main, M01
```

Your own Git software, working in your own repository—"your Git" for short—can only be on *one* of these two branches.  To represent which one you're on, let's attach the special name `HEAD` to one of these two branch names:

```
...--G--H   <-- main (HEAD), M01
```

If we now run:

```
git switch M01
```

Git will move `HEAD` over to the name `M01`:

```
...--G--H   <-- main, M01 (HEAD)
```

We're still using *commit* `H`, because both names *select the same commit*.  The set of files in your working tree will remain exactly the same, because we didn't change *commits*.

Now suppose we remove a bunch of files—perhaps an entire folder-full of files—from the working tree, and create some new files, and run `git add .` to add the removing-and-creating and then run `git commit`.  When we make this *new* commit, Git will save *all* the files that are in Git's *staging area* at that time.  The `git add .` updated the staging area to match our working tree.<sup>3</sup>  This will make a *new commit*, which will get some random-looking hash ID, but we'll just call it "commit `I`".  Let's draw it in:

```
...--G--H
         \
          I
```

Commit `I` has, as its parent, earlier commit `H`.  That's because we were using commit `H` to *make* commit `I`; we were, and still are, `on branch M01` as `git status` will say here, and just a moment ago—before we ran `git commit`—the name `M01` pointed to commit `H`.  But now that commit `I` exists, the `git commit` command wrote `I`'s hash ID into the *current branch name*, so what we have is this:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          I   <-- M01 (HEAD)
```

Commit `I` contains the files we told Git it should have; branch name `M01` selects commit `I`; and `HEAD` tells us we're on branch `M01`.  If we now run:

```
git switch main
```

Git will *remove* the files that go with commit `I` and *extract* the files that go with commit `H`.  Our working tree will now match commit `H` and we will have:

```
...--G--H   <-- main (HEAD)
         \
          I   <-- M01
```

as our commit picture.

---

<sup>2</sup>Your own Git probably defaults to `master` while GitHub now default to `main`, which creates some issues later.

<sup>3</sup>I've skipped over some important details about `.gitignore` files, tracked files, untracked files, and how the index works here, so as to concentrate on the commits-and-branches.

---

#### What you've gotten wrong

> So if I create a new local folder M02 and a branch by typing `git branch M02`, switching to it by git switch M02, It shows me all of the contents that I have previously added into the M01 branch in the M02 branch ...

The new branch and the old branch currently *share the same final commit*.

What you see when you look at your *working tree* are just your *working tree files*.  They're not the same as the committed files, although if `git status` says that everything matches, they do *match* the committed files.  The committed files do not—*cannot*—change, ever.

Note that Git stores only *files*.  The files in the commit at the end of your `M01` branch may have names like `M01/somefile`.  That's the file's actual name: `M01/somefile`.  It's not a *folder* named `M01` containing a *file* named `somefile`.  Your *working tree* has this setup—folders with files in them—and in your working tree, the slashes might even go the other way, `M01\somefile`.  In the *commit*, though, it's just a file named `M01/somefile`.  This particular point is usually not important, but it means Git is literally incapable of storing an empty folder (because an empty folder contains no files, and Git can only store *files*).<sup>4</sup>

> but If a remove the files from M02 by typing `git rm . -r` (it deletes local files), it also deletes the files from both M01 branch and M02 branch.

The `git rm -r .` operation clears out Git's index / staging-area and your working tree.  The *existing commits* do not—and cannot—change.  A *future* commit that you make right now will contain no files (because you removed all the files); as you put some files back and `git add` them, the future commit will contain those files.

Git's index / staging-area thus acts as your *proposed future commit*.  You create a file in your working tree and run `git add` to copy it into Git's staging area.  You `git checkout` or `git switch` to some existing commit to tell Git: *remove all the current committed files and swap in the files from the other commit*.  This is completely safe if you've committed everything; it's *not* safe if you have uncommitted work, and `git checkout` or `git switch` will normally detect these not-safe cases and avoid clobbering the uncommitted work.<sup>5</sup>

---

<sup>4</sup>There are some tricks with Git *submodules* that can be used here, but let's not get into those.

<sup>5</sup>Note that `git checkout` has a "dangerous" mode of operation that will clobber unsaved work.  The new `git switch` command implements the safe part of `git checkout`, while the new `git restore` command implements the unsafe part of `git checkout`.  So it's probably better to learn the new `git switch` and `git restore`, so that you always know if you're running a safety-checking command.

For various reasons, both "safe" commands will *sometimes* let you switch branches even with unsaved work.  When they *will* let you switch, but you forgot to save (add-and/or-commit) first, you can just switch back.  This gets quite complicated when one goes into full detail.  See [Checkout another branch when there are uncommitted changes on the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22053757/1256452) if you really want to know.

---

#### Some further detail

[ElpieKay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68901485/1256452) shows you how to create more than one *root commit*.  A root commit is a commit like our commit `A` above: the very first one in a new, empty repository, that has no parent commit.  Obviously that first commit *can't* have a previous commit, so Git has to be able to create a root commit.  Using `git checkout --orphan` or `git switch --orphan` is another way to create a root commit.

There is a small but critical difference between checkout and switch here:

```
git checkout --orphan newbranch
```

leaves Git's index / staging-area full of files (and does not touch your working tree at all), but:

```
git switch --orphan newbranch
```

empties out Git's index / staging-area (and as a result, removes any corresponding tracked files from your working tree).  If you intend to remove all tracked files, using `git switch --orphan` saves you this step.

Comment: This brings the complete understanding of branching! Now I can't decide which answer I should mark as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, a good solution is to create an empty root commit from the very beginning. And whenever you want to start a new branch from scratch, just create it from the root commit.

```
# create the 1st empty root commit
git init
git commit --allow-empty -m"root of all"

# tag it so that you don't have to use its sha1 value which is hard to memorize
git tag root

# create a new branch that tracks no files
git branch newbranch root
```

It's not late if you create an empty root commit now. Since your repository is not empty, we need other methods to create a root commit.

```
# create an orphan branch foo from the current branch
git checkout --orphan foo

# remove all cached files and directories
git rm --cached -rf .

# create the empty root commit
git commit --allow-empty -m "root of all"

# tag it
git tag root

# remove the orphan branch foo
git branch -D foo
```

And here's a 3rd method to create an empty root commit and tag it,

```
git tag root $(git commit-tree -m"root of all" $(git mktree < /dev/null))
```